# Is it possible to update variable which were used by the eventlistener?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, polymer, addeventlistener

I am using that script by clicking on a polymer pie chart to get details about the online and offline clients. By changing the data in my json-document the arrays until "position 1" getting the update but in the eventlistener function nothing happens. By logging I could see the that their were used the "old arrays".
Could anyone tell me the problem or my mmistake in the script?

```
<script>
    update();
    function update() {
        function callRest() {
          var array;
          $.ajax({
              url: 'http://localhost:8080/restAPI',
              type: 'GET',
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              async: false,
              success: function (data) {
                    array = JSON.parse(data);
              }
          });
          return array;
        }
        var array = callRest();
        var on = [];
        var off = [];
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            if(array[i].status=="online"){
                on[on.length] = array[i];
            }
            else if(array[i].status=="offline"){
                off[off.length] = array[i];
            }
        }

        // position 1

        function online() {
            fillData(on);
        }
        function offline() {
            fillData(off);
        }
        function fillData(array) {
            console.log(array);
        }
        document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
            var chart = document.querySelector('#chart');
            var label = document.querySelector('#selection-label');
            chart.addEventListener('google-chart-render', function() {
                chart.selection = [{row: null, column: null}];
                label.textContent =  'Für Details bitte einen Status auswählen';
            });
            document.addEventListener('google-chart-select', function(e) {
                if(chart.selection[0].row==1) offline();
                else if(chart.selection[0].row==3) online();
            });
        }, update);
    window.setTimeout(update, 10000);
  }
    </script>
```

thanks for help!

Comment: what do you mean by `By changing the data in my json-document the arrays until "position 1" getting the update`

Comment: ok anyways I found out the issue, I will post my answer.

Comment: are there any errors in console.

Comment: Can you give us a rundown of what shows in your console with this code? Possibly clarify what exactly you mean by *"By logging I could see the that their were used the "old arrays""*? Note that your code will only run twice, setTimeout isn't the same as setInterval. and... by using setTimeout or setInterval you'll get duplicate event handlers, so you'll need to somehow handle that better.

Comment: Can you tell what you get in your console?

Comment: there is a warning kind of this:
/deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.

Comment: by logging the arrays in the first part of my code the both arrays (on,off) get new values but in part of the eventlistener they have already the values they had by last page refresh

Answer (score 0):

I got fixed by putting the whole code inside of the eventlistener and just around the update-function!
But still thanks for trying to help!